# How will I solve this using DP?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, matrix, dynamic-programming

Question link: http://codeforces.com/contest/2/problem/B

There is a square matrix n × n, consisting of non-negative integer numbers. You should find such a way on it that

starts in the upper left cell of the matrix;
each following cell is to the right or down from the current cell;
the way ends in the bottom right cell.
Moreover, if we multiply together all the numbers along the way, the result should be the least "round". In other words, it should end in the least possible number of zeros.

Input
The first line contains an integer number n (2 ≤ n ≤ 1000), n is the size of the matrix. Then follow n lines containing the matrix elements (non-negative integer numbers not exceeding 10^9).

Output
In the first line print the least number of trailing zeros. In the second line print the correspondent way itself.

I thought of the following: In the end, whatever the answer will be, it should contain minimum powers of 2's and 5's. Therefore, what I did was, for each entry in the input matrix, I calculated the powers of 2's and 5's and stored them in separate matrices.

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin>>foo;
            matrix[i][j] = foo;
            int n1 = calctwo(foo);   // calculates the number of 2's in factorisation of that number
            int n2 = calcfive(foo); // calculates number of 5's
            two[i][j] = n1;
            five[i][j] = n2;
        }
    }
```

After that, I did this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        dp[i][j] = min(two[i][j],five[i][j]);  // Here, dp[i][j] will store minimum number of 2's and 5's. 
    }
}
```

But the above doesn't really a valid answer, I don't know why? Have I implemented the correct approach? Or, is this the correct way of solving this question?

Edit: Here are my functions of calculating the number of two's and number of five's in a number.

```
int calctwo (int foo)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (foo%2 == 0)
    {
        if (foo%2 == 0)
        {
            counter++;
            foo = foo/2;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return counter;
}

int calcfive (int foo)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (foo%5 == 0)
    {
        if (foo%5 == 0)
        {
            counter++;
            foo = foo/5;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Edit2: I/O Example as given in the link:

Input:

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output:

```
0
DDRR
```

Comment: You are going to need a _lot_ more work than a few lines of C code to solve this.  I would use a recursive approach.

Comment: not necessary, @TimBiegeleisen,a simple code would work using dp.

Comment: @vish4071, how can I improve it then?

Comment: Who said the product is only multiples of 2's and 5's?  E.g. `1 * 2 * 3 * 6* 9 = 324`

Comment: Your calculation of 2's and 5's is alright. But making 2 matrices is not advisable. Do you use cpp?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the number is not only product of 2's and 5's, but these are the only factors which are of concern (as these are factors of 10)

Comment: @rohansingh, wait for 5 min, I'll write a code in cpp and post it as answer.

Comment: @vish4071, alright and yes I use cpp. Thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: It took a lot of time to comment, and initially, I  didn't see that you had to print path, so it took some time.

Comment: How will you solve this then? I am now all the more scared of DP than I began with. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are interested only in the number of trailing zeroes you need only to consider the powers of `2`, `5` which you could keep in two separate `nxn` arrays. So for the array

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

you just keep the arrays

```
the powers of 2    the powers of 5       
0 1 0              0 0 0
2 0 1              0 1 0
0 3 0              0 0 0
```

The insight for the problem is the following. Notice that if you find a path which minimizes the sum of the powers of 2 and a path which minimizes the number sum of the powers of 5 then the answer is the one with lower value of those two paths. So you reduce your problem to the two times application of the following classical dp problem: find a path, starting from the top-left corner and ending at the bottom-right,  such that the sum of its elements is minimum. Again, following the example, we have:

```
 minimal path for the 
 powers of 2                 value
 * * -                         2
 - * * 
 - - *

 minimal path for the 
 powers of 5                 value
 * - -                         0
 * - - 
 * * *
```

so your answer is

```
 * - -                      
 * - - 
 * * *
```

with value `0`

**Note 1**

It might seem that taking the minimum of the both optimal paths gives only an upper bound so a question that may rise is: is this bound actually achieved? The answer is yes. For convenience, let the number of 2's along the 2's optimal path is `a` and the number of 5's along the 5's optimal path is `b`. Without loss of generality assume that the minimum of the both optimal paths is the one for the power of 2's (that is `a < b`). Let the number of 5's along the minimal path is `c`. Now the question is: are there as much as 5's as there are 2's along this path (i.e. is `c >= a`?). Assume that the answer is no. That means that there are less 5's than 2's along the minimal path (that is `c < a`). Since the optimal value of 5's paths is `b` we have that every 5's path has at least `b` 5's in it. This should also be true for the minimal path. That means that `c > b`. We have that `c < a` so `a > b` but the initial assumption was that `a < b`. Contradiction.

**Note 2**

You might also want consider the case in which there is an element `0` in your matrix. I'd assume that number of trailing zeroes when the product is 1. In this case, if the algorithm has produced a result with a value more than 1 you should output 1 and print a path that goes through the element `0`.

Comment: I have a doubt in this. Let's say the path for the matrix in 2's is `(RRDD)` and let's say the sum of powers is 3. Similarly, the sum of path for the matrix in 5's is `(DDRR)` (similar to the one you have made) and it's value is 2. However, also, assume that the elements lying along the shorter value path (that is, along the path value 2) have no 2's in their prime factorisation. Then, there will be no 0's in output but according to your logic, it will still print two.

Comment: @rohansingh You have to give it more thought.  In your example the optimal path for the 5's has value `2` and you say what if there are less than `2` in total power of 2's along this 5's optimal path ( you say what if there are 0 in total power of 2's). Suppose that is true. We'd then have that there exist a path with value less `2` but this is impossible since your minimum value for the 2's paths is `3`

Comment: @Inwvr, that's right. Sorry, my bad. I am gonna try and implement this and will revert back if in case I have any doubts. Thanks a lot though. Your solution is extremely elegant. :)

Comment: That is actually a correct solution. Very good. Although I would exclude the zero-case (because it is not clear if 0 is allowed and if 0 has 1 or zero trailing zeroes).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. I've used `pair<int,int>` to store factor of 2 and 5 in the matrix.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define pii pair<int,int> 
#define F first 
#define S second
#define MP make_pair

int calc2(int a){
    int c=0;
    while(a%2==0){
        c++;
        a/=2;
    }
    return c;
}

int calc5(int a){
    int c=0;
    while(a%5==0){
        c++;
        a/=5;
    }
    return c;
}

int mini(int a,int b){
    return a<b?a:b;
}

pii min(pii a, pii b){
    if(mini(a.F,a.S) < mini(b.F,b.S))
        return a;
    return b;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<vector<pii > > v;
    vector<vector<int> > path;

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        vector<pii > x;
        vector<int> q(n,0);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            int y;cin>>y;
            x.push_back(MP(calc2(y),calc5(y)));   //I store factors of 2,5 in the vector to calculate
        }
        x.push_back(MP(100000,100000));     //padding each row to n+1 elements (to handle overflow in code)
        v.push_back(x);
        path.push_back(q);     //initialize path matrix to 0
    }

    vector<pii > x(n+1,MP(100000,100000));
    v.push_back(x);               //pad 1 more row to handle index overflow

    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--){          //move from destination to source grid
            if(i==n-1 && j==n-1)
                continue;

            //here, the LHS of condition in if block is the condition which determines minimum number of trailing 0's. This is the same condition that is used to manipulate "v" for getting the same result. 
            if(min(MP(v[i][j].F+v[i+1][j].F,v[i][j].S+v[i+1][j].S), MP(v[i][j].F+v[i][j+1].F,v[i][j].S+v[i][j+1].S)) == MP(v[i][j].F+v[i+1][j].F,v[i][j].S+v[i+1][j].S))
                path[i][j] = 1;         //go down
            else
                path[i][j] = 2;         //go right
            v[i][j] = min(MP(v[i][j].F+v[i+1][j].F,v[i][j].S+v[i+1][j].S), MP(v[i][j].F+v[i][j+1].F,v[i][j].S+v[i][j+1].S));
        }
    }

    cout<<mini(v[0][0].F, v[0][0].S)<<endl;   //print result
    for(i=0,j=0;i<=n-1 && j<=n-1;){           //print path (I don't know o/p format)
        cout<<"("<<i<<","<<j<<") -> ";
        if(path[i][j]==1)
            i++;
        else
            j++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives fine results as far as the test cases I checked. If you have any doubts regarding this code, ask in comments.

EDIT:
The basic thought process. 
To reach the destination, there are only 2 options. I started with destination to avoid the problem of path ahead calculation, because if 2 have same minimum values, then we chose any one of them. If the path to destination is already calculated, it does not matter which we take.

And minimum is to check which pair is more suitable. If a pair has minimum 2's or 5's than other, it will produce less 0's.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, both the cases give output `0`.

Comment: @vish4071, can you explain how the conditions, that is, the `min` ones, and also, why did you start from the end? And what's the logic really to solve this question?

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I don't see a problem with that. I move from destination to source.So, `path ahead` is already calculated to be minimum. Every permutation of the test case you are giving is producing `0` as o/p.

Comment: Found the problematic case: input order of your program: 1, 5, 100, 25, 1, 2, 100, 25, 1. Output should be zero trailing zeroes (path 1, 25, 1, 5, 1).

Comment: @NicoSchertler, thanks for the test case. After I checked the cases you gave earlier, I tried submitting the code on the link. It obvs gave WA. :(

Comment: @vish4071, also in the comments you have written, go down and go right. If you are moving from destination to source, won't they be go left and go up? Sorry, I am asking really silly doubts but I am not able to make it properly. Thanks!

Comment: yes, that is it exactly. But the reason I started from destination is no longer valid. So the answer is not exacly correct. I'll improvise it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution proposal using Javascript and functional programming.
It relies on several functions:

- the core function is `smallest_trailer` that recursively goes through the grid. I have chosen to go in 4 possible direction, left "L", right "R", down "D" and "U". It is not possible to pass twice on the same cell. The direction that is chosen is the one with the smallest number of trailing zeros. The counting of trailing zeros is devoted to another function.
- the function `zero_trailer(p,n,nbz)` assumes that you arrive on a cell with a value `p` while you already have an accumulator `n` and met `nbz` zeros on your way. The function returns an array with two elements, the new number of zeros and the new accumulator. The accumulator will be a power of 2 or 5. The function uses the auxiliary function `pow_2_5(n)` that returns the powers of 2 and 5 inside `n`.
- Other functions are more anecdotical: `deepCopy(arr)` makes a standard deep copy of the array `arr`, `out_bound(i,j,n)` returns true if the cell `(i,j)` is out of bound of the grid of size `n`, `myMinIndex(arr)` returns the  min index of an array of 2 dimensional arrays (each subarray contains the nb of trailing zeros and the path as a string). The min is only taken on the first element of subarrays.
- `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is a (large) constant for the maximal number of trailing zeros when the path is wrong (goes out of bound for example).

Here is the code, which works on the example given in the comments above and in the orginal link.

```
var MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991;

function pow_2_5(n) {
  // returns the power of 2 and 5 inside n
  function pow_not_2_5(k) {
    if (k%2===0) {
      return pow_not_2_5(k/2);
    }
    else if (k%5===0) {
      return pow_not_2_5(k/5);
    }
    else {
      return k;
    }
  }
  return n/pow_not_2_5(n);
}

function zero_trailer(p,n,nbz) {
  // takes an input two numbers p and n that should be multiplied and a given initial number of zeros (nbz = nb of zeros)
  // n is the accumulator of previous multiplications (a power of 5 or 2)
  // returns an array [kbz, k] where kbz is the total new number of zeros (nbz + the trailing zeros from the multiplication of p and n)
  // and k is the new accumulator (typically a power of 5 or 2)
  function zero_aux(k,kbz) {
    if (k===0) {
      return [1,0];
    }
    else if (k%10===0) {
      return zero_aux(k/10,kbz+1);
    }
    else {
      return [kbz,k];
    }
  }
  return zero_aux(pow_2_5(p)*n,nbz);  
}

function out_bound(i,j,n) {
  return !((i>=0)&&(i<n)&&(j>=0)&&(j<n));
}

function deepCopy(arr){
  var toR = new Array(arr.length);
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var toRi = new Array(arr[i].length);
    for(var j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
      toRi[j] = arr[i][j];
    }
    toR[i] = toRi;
  }
  return toR;
}

function myMinIndex(arr) {
  var min = arr[0][0];
  var minIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i][0] < min) {
          minIndex = i;
          min = arr[i][0];
      }
  }
  return minIndex;
}

function smallest_trailer(grid) {
  var n = grid.length;
  function st_aux(i,j,grid_aux, acc_mult, nb_z, path) {

    if ((i===n-1)&&(j===n-1)) {          
      var tmp_acc_nbz_f = zero_trailer(grid_aux[i][j],acc_mult,nb_z);
      return [tmp_acc_nbz_f[0], path];
    }
    else if (out_bound(i,j,n)) {
      return [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,[]];
    }
    else if (grid_aux[i][j]<0) {
      return [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,[]];
    }
    else {
      var tmp_acc_nbz = zero_trailer(grid_aux[i][j],acc_mult,nb_z) ;
      grid_aux[i][j]=-1;
      var res = [st_aux(i+1,j,deepCopy(grid_aux), tmp_acc_nbz[1], tmp_acc_nbz[0], path+"D"), 
                 st_aux(i-1,j,deepCopy(grid_aux), tmp_acc_nbz[1], tmp_acc_nbz[0], path+"U"),
                 st_aux(i,j+1,deepCopy(grid_aux), tmp_acc_nbz[1], tmp_acc_nbz[0], path+"R"),
                 st_aux(i,j-1,deepCopy(grid_aux), tmp_acc_nbz[1], tmp_acc_nbz[0], path+"L")];
      return res[myMinIndex(res)];      
    }
  }
  return st_aux(0,0,grid, 1, 0, "");
}

myGrid = [[1, 25, 100],[2, 1, 25],[100, 5, 1]];
console.log(smallest_trailer(myGrid)); //[0,"RDDR"]
myGrid = [[1, 2, 100],[25, 1, 5],[100, 25, 1]];
console.log(smallest_trailer(myGrid)); //[0,"DRDR"]
myGrid = [[1, 10, 1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 10, 1],[10, 10, 10, 10, 1],[10, 10, 10, 10, 1],[10, 10, 10, 10, 1]];
console.log(smallest_trailer(myGrid)); //[0,"DRRURRDDDD"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my Dynamic Programming solution.

https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingAXFQ5B-SZQ/

For better understanding we can simplify the task and assume that there are no zeros in the matrix (i.e. matrix contains only positive integers), then the Java solution will be the following:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[][] a) {
        int minPws[][] = new int[a.length][a[0].length];

        int minPws2 = getMinPws(a, minPws, 2);
        int minPws5 = getMinPws(a, minPws, 5);
        return min(minPws2, minPws5);
    }

    private int getMinPws(int[][] a, int[][] minPws, int p) {
        minPws[0][0] = pws(a[0][0], p);
        //Fullfill the first row
        for (int j = 1; j < a[0].length; j++) {
            minPws[0][j] = minPws[0][j-1] + pws(a[0][j], p);
        }
        //Fullfill the first column
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            minPws[i][0] = minPws[i-1][0] + pws(a[i][0], p);
        }
        //Fullfill the rest of matrix
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                minPws[i][j] = min(minPws[i-1][j], minPws[i][j-1]) + pws(a[i][j], p);
            }
        }

        return minPws[a.length-1][a[0].length-1];
    }

    private int pws(int n, int p) {
        //Only when n > 0
        int pws = 0;
        while (n % p == 0) {
            pws++;
            n /= p;
        }
        return pws;
    }

    private int min(int a, int b) {
        return (a < b) ? a : b;
    }
}
```